# JQuery string length

Tags: jquery, string, string-length

I try to find the length of a string with jquery but it doesn't work...

Here a JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/3LtjdkLw/1/

HTML code:

```
<div id="signup-pwd">ABC</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
alert($('#signup-pwd').val().length)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a `<div>`, unlike `<input>`, `<select>` and `<textarea>` elements, has a `textContent`/`innerText` property rather than `value`, so you should use `text()` instead of `val()`:

```
$('#signup-pwd').text().length;
```

[Updated JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3LtjdkLw/3/).

References:

- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Answer (score 1):

You need `.text()` not `.val()` to get the text value inside a textual HTML element.